# DDD: Decoupling repositories from a document DB when a Unit of Work doesn't apply

Tags: domain-driven-design, azure-cosmosdb

I am introducing Azure Cosmos DB's `DocumentClient` into a `DDD` project, but I'm having difficulties in decoupling my repositories from `DocumentClient`.

Currently, the project uses Entity Framework, where I inject into my repositories a `IUnitOfWork`, and the repositories call `IUnitOfWork.Commit()` when they complete the changes. (I'm skipping other details but that's the high-level overview.)

However, it doesn't feel right to use `IUnitOfWork` with `DocumentClient`, because it justs performs HTTP requests to an URI for CRUD operations.

I could perfectly inject `IDocumentClient` into my repositories, but I would be coupling them to Azure Cosmos DB and I would not be following `DDD` best practices.

What does `DDD` recommend in these cases?

Comment: Would it make more sense to use something like [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) as your ORM and just inject the ICosmosStore of your respective object?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I wasn't aware of it, I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection, and transaction handling for that matter, should be handled in the application/integration layer.

This means that a repository would perform data-oriented operations but would never open/close connections or perform transactions such as `commit`.

In your example your unit of work `commit` call would then be interacting over `http` on the appropriate level.

Comment: In my domain layer, I create the repository interfaces for each aggregate root. Then, based on your answer, the implementation of these interfaces would go to the application layer. Did I get that right? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, repository interfaces are part of the domain model.  The implementation of the interface is part of infrastructure.  How you choose to package that would be a matter of convenience or preference.  But *logically* it is infrastructure.  In my projects I would have a `Product.DataAccess`assembly of sorts.  In many cases I even have the `namespace` in the same assembly as the domain model simply because I have no need to split it out.  I am careful to remain cognizant of the fact that I *can* split it out at any time though.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's [CosmosDb provider for EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), which means that You don't have to worry about document client - EF abstracts it for You.